# Assistance Fixing While Loop

Tags: python, while-loop, pycharm

Below is what I'm trying to do:

1. Prompt user with the question "Do you want to add a student? "
2. If user enters "Yes" they will be prompted with "Who do you want to add? "
3. After adding the student's name, they will be prompted again with "Do you want to add a student? " until the user enters "No"
4. If the user enters "No", I want to print all the students the user has entered.

With the little I know, I attempt to code it below:

```
students = []


initial_input = 'Yes'
second_input = ''

while initial_input == 'Yes':
    initial_input = input('Do you want to add a student? ')
    if initial_input == 'Yes':
        second_input = input('Who do you want to add? ')

        if initial_input == 'No':
            students.append(second_input)

print(students)
```

When running it, it doesn't print out the names I entered below:

```
Do you want to add a user? Yes
Who do you want to add? John
Do you want to add a user? Yes
Who do you want to add? Tim
Do you want to add a user? No
[]

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Can someone kindly explain what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: you should append `second_input` to your list right after you got it.

Comment: and you don't need the `if inital_input == 'No'`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: Kevin and Red. Thanks for the input. It worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a simple placement issue. Your appending of the student only comes if they put 'no' to adding a student. Try this:

```
while initial_input == 'Yes':
    initial_input = input('Do you want to add a student? ')
    if initial_input == 'Yes':
        second_input = input('Who do you want to add? ')
        students.append(second_input)

print(students)
```

Comment: Worked Perfectly. Thanks Craig!